# Windows 2012 R2 start button not working over RDP

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

It seems that when I RDP to some 2012 R2 machines, the start button seems to become un-responsive (Highlight doesn't even appear over the icon).

Failing over to ye'old ALT+Home still works a charm however.

A reboot resolves the problem, but it does intermittently return after.  Has anyone experienced this or knows how to fix without rebooting production servers.

Comment: I don't have solution for you, but you can also use "shutdown -r" to restart, "shutdown -l" to log off. Since I myself always have a command prompt open, works great for me.

Comment: I got this problem recently on our VPS Server running Windows 2016. Start button and Action Center are both not working. Right click menu works. Tried the solutions here. None worked. Reboot didn't solve the problem either :(

Answer (score 9):

I see the same problem, and found a workaround by moving the task bar to the left or right side of the screen, and suddenly it Works Again. (moving it back to the lower left corner, breaks it Again)

Comment: This didn't work for me :(

Comment: Simply restart process File Manager will solved it.

Comment: killing explorer.exe from task manager and then again running it resolved it. Thanks @sing10407

Comment: This time I couldn't find Explorer.exe in task manager. So I open powershell by typing powershell in Run and then entered this which fixed the issue: `Stop-process -name "Explorer"`

Comment: Worked for me  :-)  +1

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem. If you open task manager under details, there are 2 explorer.exe running. End both tasks and run new task type explorer will work.

Comment: Only 1 Windows Explorer instance running, however when I ended the task, restart fixed this.  Weird.

Answer (score -3):

Sign out and then sign back in again. That fixed it for me.

Comment: Perhaps if you explain why you would need to logoff and log back on again you could assist the OP in understanding why that would fix the issue they are experiencing.

Comment: how do you sign out without using the start-menu?

Comment: Use the Windows key instead. It will work